# How to block clients by IP address from accessing certain URLs on my web server?

Tags: firewall, webserver

How can I permanently block any ipaddress who accesses known vulnerable pages such as `/phpMyadmin/`? 
I am running a Debian server and I often see bots, or hackers scanning my server trying to find vulnerabilities.

```
73.199.136.112 - - [16/Oct/2017:05:18:05 -0700] "HEAD /phpMyadmin/ HTTP/1.0" 404 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
73.199.136.112 - - [16/Oct/2017:05:18:05 -0700] "HEAD /phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.0" 404 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
73.199.136.112 - - [16/Oct/2017:05:18:05 -0700] "HEAD /phpmyAdmin/ HTTP/1.0" 404 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
73.199.136.112 - - [16/Oct/2017:05:18:05 -0700] "HEAD /phpmyadmin2/ HTTP/1.0" 404 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
73.199.136.112 - - [16/Oct/2017:05:18:05 -0700] "HEAD /phpmyadmin3/ HTTP/1.0" 404 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
73.199.136.112 - - [16/Oct/2017:05:18:05 -0700] "HEAD /phpmyadmin4/ HTTP/1.0" 404 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
```

I have followed this stackoverflow question already: [How to secure phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631269/how-to-secure-phpmyadmin).

I am looking to start blocking bots from taking up bandwidth.

Comment: This will clean up you log files, but won't help with security at all. Either always keep you phpmyadmin up-to-date, or access it only from localhost (and block all other traffic). To access the remote server, tunnel the port via ssh.

Comment: I think it will help security because it will block the malicious IP addresses who try to access that site.

Comment: @Whitecat the `404` HTTP code means `Page not found`. How do you sense that these IP's are offending IP's? Based on what output do you decide to block these IP's?

Comment: I want to block the ip based on the fact that they are going to phpMyAdmin. I have secured my site and I know anyone going to that page is malicious.

Comment: Why don't you create a `.htpasswd`

Comment: @nicoX I am not interested in blocking just for phpmyadmin. That is just one way to identify a bad actor trying to get access to my website.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This may be more heavy weight than you're looking for, but you might consider using fail2ban (https://www.fail2ban.org).  That's a tool that can monitor your log files and automatically ban addresses that generate logs that match a set of customizable patterns.

Comment: tbh this is exact problem `fail2ban` is designed to address. It's a bit heavy but then again the desired criteria is fairly dynamic itself. All things considered `fail2ban` is about as light weight as you're going to get in trying to solve this class of problems using a standard tool.

Comment: Well I suppose you could write a suid-root binary cgi, host it as /phpmyadmin, that adds the firewall rule of its caller.

Answer (score 7):

Don't. At best you'll achieve nothing but making your logs less cluttered; at worst you'll end up **blocking legitimate visitors** who happened to get (via DHCP) an IP address that used to belong to someone whose PC was infected as a botnet node.

The real problem here is the log clutter, and it can be solved just by configuring your logging to drop requests that are known vuln-scanning for vulns your site doesn't, and won't, have because you're not using the vulnerable frameworks they're scanning for. If you're concerned about complete loss of logging (perhaps they provide evidence suggesting who was responsible for a different attack, or when an attack began, etc.) then just throttling multiple log entries for junk URLs from a given IP in a short timespan should work better.

Comment: `fail2ban` bans are temporary - X hits of a bad login attempt within Y seconds, Z minute ban, with configurable X Y and Z. Dropping logs of active intrusion attempts sounds to me like a significantly more dangerous choice.

Comment: You make a great point. I should not perm block the ip addresses. I can create temporary blocks.

Comment: In that case it's less of a problem, but still doesn't seem terribly helpful.

Comment: @Shadur: Made a slight update to improve on that.

Comment: in the 0.1% chance this happens, legitimate users to this instance of *phpmyadmin* should be able to just message OP to get unblocked. Also, fail2ban can shut out a scanning attack before it happens to hit the unpatched or zero day vulnerability on your server.

Comment: @Segfault: There presumably are no legitimate users of `/phymyadmin/` because `/phymyadmin/` doesn't exist on the server (see: 404). Rather the legitimate users in question are **any users of the site** who would be blocked by firewalling them.

Comment: @R ok, good point. I assumed he actually did have a phpmyadmin instance since he went through the article to secure it. The 404 could just mean that it's installed to a different path after all.

Comment: The "best" actually includes further tests being blocked including ones that might have actually succeeded. Playing around with the log contents also seems like a good way to lose information when you realize you've made some sort of error in your filter. If you're worried about log clutter then you need an analytics platform like ELK to sift through it all for the stuff you're interested in.

Comment: The other, related, issue is the increasing use of CGN. An ISP can have hundreds of customers sharing a single IP address, making IP blocking dangerous at best, even temporary ones. You can have a legitimate user and an active scan from the same address at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

find the phpMyAdmin.conf in one of the httpd config directories and add `deny 73.199.136.112` in allow / deny section of the config file and a require IP in the 2.4 section. I have put an example of the full config file below where I have the entries in reverse, i block everything but the allowed IP segments to access the tool.

```
[thebtm@server conf.d]# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
# 
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 10.10.26
       Require ip 192.168.56
       Require ip 127.0.0.1       
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 10.10.25
     Allow from 192.168.56
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is awesome. But the problem is there are constant bots from many different ip's. I cannot possibly keep up with every different IP as I get between 20-30 unique malicious ips per day.

Comment: That is why I showed the reverse where you allow the segments you want to have access and auto block the rest.

Comment: `Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmind` `/phpmyadmin` should be changed to something else for security purposes.

`Alias /secret /usr/share/phpMyAdmind`

Comment: I modified the default config file that comes with the tool when you install it and made up some random IP addresses.